# Pegar Imagem Separadamente com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagem

estou com um problema que acho que para vocês será bem simples de resolver. Montei um preview de imagens e preciso remover cada imagem separadamente, porém, não estou conseguindo, estou tentando pegar pelo id. As imagens ficam dentro de uma div chamada output_box_foto. Eu criei um contador para atribuir id's diferentes para cada imagem.

Eis o código abaixo:

```
for(var i=0;i<total_file;i++)
    {
        // Only process image files.
          if (!files_show[i].type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
          }
        $('#output_box_foto').append("<img class='thumb' id='"+contador_img+"' src='"+URL.createObjectURL(files_show[i])+"'><br/><span class='remove'>Remover</span>").on('click', function() {
                id = $("#output_box_foto").find('img').attr('id');  
                alert(id);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize o evento onclick na tag span marcada com a classe 'remove' e crie uma função que recebe o id da imagem a ser removida. Exemplo (adaptei o seu código pois não tinha acesso aos valores de algumas variáveis):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var total_file = 5;
    var contador_img = 0;

    for(var i=0;i<total_file;i++)
    {
        $('#output_box_foto').append("<img class='thumb' id='"+contador_img+"' src=''><br/><span class='remove' onclick='Remover("+contador_img+")'>Remover</span>");

        contador_img++;
    }
});

function Remover(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

O teste funcional do exemplo pode ser conferido aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/marcellalves/1my79wty/

Comment: Muito obrigado Marcell, Problema resolvido!